# Advice required for network setup including web server, air printer and external devices

Tags: wireless-networking, internet, wireless-router, printer

I'm wondering if anyone can tell me if the following network setup will work as required, and if there are any watchouts/red flags to address.

To start with, the requirements: 1) a main device running a web server should have access to the internet and an air printer connected on the same wifi network 2) other devices should be able to connect to the web server using an internal IP address (i.e. not via the internet) 3) the other devices should not have access to the air printer or the internet.

I've identified a nice cheap TP-LINK router that supports the use of a 4G USB dongle for internet connectivity, whilst also apparently being able to block access to websites that are not on a white list. I appreciate that blocking websites != blocking the internet, but for now lets move on. Whilst this router can provide a guest network for other devices to connect to, it does not appear able to prevent these connections selectively allowing access to certain LAN IP addresses (i.e. the device running the web server), which means that it will most likely be able to see the AirPrinter. I've tested something like this on my Asus router at home and indeed as long as LAN Access is enabled, the connecting guest device can see my AirPrinter. Bad!

My solution for this is to add a second TP-LINK router running in Access Point mode, connecting that to the first router, defining a different SSID, and then having all other devices connecting to the second router. I've tried this also at home and in my test, the second router was given an IP on the same subnet as the main router and whilst I could connect fine to it using my phone, I could not see the AirPrinter that was connected to the main router. I was still able, however, to connect to the web server running on the the main router. Great.

I'm really looking for validation of this approach, any suggestions for how it might be improved (e.g. sticking the second router on a subnet, and then enabling a route from it to the specific IP address of the web server on the main router?) and if there are any more effective ways of blocking internet access from the second router entirely (rather than just by the whitelist on the main router).

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

This approach is probably not very secure but may stop casual attempts to access the printer.  I expect that while the printer can't be scanned for (because its not on the same subnet as the devices scanning it), you could add the printer by IP address.   You can most likely even find the IP address by doing a port scan.   (You might have slightly better luck if you reverse the first and second router - IE have the printer and web server behind NAT, use port mapping and add routes to your main router - which will isolate the printer and web server, however you will have difficulties limiting Internet with this solution)

**A more viable approach**

Its non trivial (but then again, any good solution to this problem will be non-trivial), but if you get a router capable of running dd-wrt and flash dd-wrt on it, you should be able to do everything you are wanting to do - below is some general guidance on the rough steps -

You want to create 2 SSIDS (virtual networks) - one for the server and printer, and the other for your other devices.   That is fairly straight forward to do - you just add virtual interfaces in the Wireless->Basic Settings menu.  You will want the network configuration unbridged, and to provide a second IP address and Subnet mask to the main SSID.  I've not played with it, but I'd imagine that if you leave NAT disabled devices connecting on the second SSID will not be able to connect to the Internet.

Once you have applied this you would go to Setup -> Networking and, in the DHCPD option, add IP address ranges for the SSID.

Next you will want to assign the printer a static IP address - You can either do this on the printer itself, or you can use Static Leases under Services -> Static Leases.   You will want to do something similar for the web server.

The last part, which is where it gets a bit tricky - is to write firewall rules to limit access to the printer.    There are a few ways you can do this.  I've not played with this method, but the easiest method is probably to write the appropriate rules under administration -> commands.  The idea here is to write a rule which only allows access to the server and router (so the clients can do DNS lookups) from the second SSID.  There are lots of ways of doing it which will be subtly different depending on your configuration - but you are looking at adding rules like :

```
/sbin/iptables -I FORWARD -s SSID2.IP.RANGE netmask SSID.IP.NETMASK -j DROP
/sbin/iptables -I FORWARD -s SSID2.IP.RANGE -d IP.ADDR.OF.SERVER -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Wonderful, thank you. I'll look further in to this. Something support people at TP-Link mentioned was the use of a managed switch running two VLANS, and using ACLs to allow/deny the various access requirements. There would be a router providing internet access, and a wifi access point where all devices would connect. I have absolutely no experience of Managed Switches and VLANS though, and I don't know if they can be used for my purposes.

Comment: My guess is that if the TPLink router supports ACLs then you don't need to worry about managed switches (but they are not that hard) as 4 vlans is more then you need - and a lot of this depends on how your devices connect - I assumed it was all wireless in my answer, but you should be able to use a VLAN in place of/in conjunction with an SSID - a VLAN is a way of grouping and isolating devices, analogous in some ways to an SSID.